# Creating doIfEmpty operator in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

I have 2 streams, the first stream is a stream which takes data from database and call `onCompleted()` after finish taking data. The second stream is a stream that takes live data from server and never call `onCompleted()`. What I want to do is to create an operator that can do an action if the first stream(upstream) is an empty stream. Here is the sample:

```
getItemFromDatabase()
.lift(new DoIfEmptyOperator<Item>(new Action0() {
                        @Override
                        public void call() {
                            //Database is empty
                            System.out.println("Yeay successfully do an action");
                        }
                    }))
.concatWith(getItemFromServer())  // -----> intentionally never complete
.subscribe(new Subscriber<StoryItem>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {
                           //dosomething... 
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                           //dosomething...
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(StoryItem storyItem) {
                           //dosomething
                        }
                    }));
```

Here is the code of DoIfEmptyOperator:

```
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;
import rx.functions.Action0;

public class DoIfEmptyOperator<T> implements Observable.Operator<T,T>{
    private Action0 action;
    private boolean isEmpty = true;

    public DoIfEmptyOperator(Action0 action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public Subscriber<? super T> call(final Subscriber<? super T> childSubscriber) {

        Subscriber<T> parentSubscriber = new Subscriber<T>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                if(isEmpty) {
                    action.call();
                }

                childSubscriber.onCompleted();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                childSubscriber.onError(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(T t) {
                isEmpty = false;
                childSubscriber.onNext(t);
            }
        };

        childSubscriber.add(parentSubscriber);

        return parentSubscriber;
    }
}
```

However the action is never executed because the parentSubscriber `onCompleted()` is not firing, because the downstream never completed. If I remove

> .concatWith(getItemFromServer())

then the action is executed. Any clue about how to solve the problem? I have dived to the source code of Observable.switchIfEmpty() but still have no clue about how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise against creating an operator.
This could be easily done with existing operators like this:

```
    getItemFromDatabase()
            .toList()
            .flatMap(list -> {
                if (list.isEmpty()) {
                    // side effect here
                }
                return getItemFromServer();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about `switchIfEmpty()`? As an example of the usage of this operator - I have created some code on GitHub at the following link:

https://github.com/rs146/rxjava-simple/blob/master/src/test/java/SwitchIfEmpty.java

`switchIfEmpty()` is called when no items are emitted.

However, if you want to get items from the api or the db, then you can do something like the following:

```
Observable.concat(getFromDatabase(), getFromApi()).first();
```

As long as both `getFromDatabase()` and `getFromApi()` return the same Observable Type. This is a common Rx idiom in Android apps. It basically states that if an item's is not emitted from the database, then go fetch the result from the API instead.

Comment: Actually I just want to do an action if the list is empty, however switchIfEmpty operator doesn't have action as parameter. Seems like bellol 's solution works.. Thanks in advance for answering @blackpather :)

Comment: @SalacceoVanz sure - however, in terms of functional programming and the Rx way of doing things - the solution using concat and retrieving the first item is actually the more cleaner option. Of course, you can test if lists are empty - however, that's not really the "functional" style.

Comment: @blackpanter However with concat, you can't know if the first item fetched is from api or from database (cause the item type is similar)... if you can know that the first item is fetched from api stream (so it is assumed that the db is empty and do something), then it maybe a cleaner solution :)